# Peculiar velocities, density gradients and geodesic motion

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, reference-frames, density, geodesics

I am studying cosmology and I have learnt that the galaxies in the universe can be represented by a pressureless fluid. Therefore, they have a **geodesic motion** (the so called matter frame). When discussing this with a colleague, I was told that, when **peculiar velocities** are taken into accout, the movements are no longer geodesic. The reason is the fact that these movements are generated by **density gradients**.

I would like to know if this claim is true and, if it is, could someone help me understand **why density gradients would "behave" as a non-gravitational force**.
Thank you very much

Comment: It is not my field but I have read that it that case (when particle mass changes) elements of the cosmic fluid moves on so-called quasi-geodesics. Seee Valerio Faraonia , Geneviève Vachonb, Quasi-geodesics in relativistic gravity, https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.05891 .

Comment: geodesic equation means $\dot{u}^a=u^b\nabla_bu^a =0$ (if affinely parameterized) and peculiar velocity is part of total 4-velocity $u^a$. However, if you model peculiar velocities as corrections on background FRW space-time, then you will have to consider it separately.  High symmetry of FRW models mean $\dot{u}^a$ and density gradient will vanish. This is not true for other models having fluid inhomogeneities. Have a look at these lectures:  https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9812046